# Writing Junit test cases to test catch clause

Tags: java, junit5

I have the following code:

```
class Hd {
  public Hd() {
     try {
       this.hName =  InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
     } catch (UnknownHostException e){
       this.setHName("unk-host");
     }
  } 
}
```

How do I write a unit test case for this constructor for the part where it throws an exception?
Since that would require `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()` to throw an exception, which may or may not happen naturally. It's like ensuring that this throws an exception always.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly accomplish it with the Dependency Injection pattern.

For example if you created an interface something like:

```java
public interface HostNameSupplier {
    String getHostName() throws UnknownHostException;
}
```

And if you created a default implementation of that interface like:

```java
public class DefaultHostNameSupplier implements HostNameSupplier {

    @Override
    public String getHostName() throws UnknownHostException {
        return InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
    }
}
```

then your `Hd` class could be set up so that a `HostNameSupplier` can be "injected" into it.

```java
public class Hd {
    
    private final String hName;

    public Hd(final HostNameSupplier hostNameSupplier) {
        String hostName;
        try {
            hostName = hostNameSupplier.getHostName();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            hostName = "unk-host";
        }
        this.hName = hostName;
    }
}
```

In your real code, you'd inject a new DefaultHostNameSupplier() into your `Hd` instance, but in your tests you can create a fake implementation of that interface that throws the exception:

```java
@Test
void shouldSetHNameToDefaultValueWhenUnknownHostExceptionThrown() {
    final Hd hd = new Hd(new HostNameSupplierThatThrowsException());
    assertEquals("unk-host", hd.getHName());
}

static class HostNameSupplierThatThrowsException implements HostNameSupplier {
    @Override
    public String getHostName() throws UnknownHostException {
        throw new UnknownHostException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just injecting the host name would be even simpler.

Comment: @johanneslink In order to just inject the host name, you have to first get the host name, and the OP wants a default value of "unk-host" if an exception is thrown when getting the host name. Whether the logic exists inside their Hd class or outside, the OP's question is how to test the part that throws an exception. Since the OP already had logic inside the class for getting the host name, that's what I used in my example.